# Mail Form submission godaddy

Tags: html, css

I have the following mail form on my website.

```
<div class="col-md-8 fade-up">
     <h3>Drop Us A Message</h3>
     <br>
     <br>
     <div id="message"></div>
        <form method="post" action="/webformmailer.php" id="contactform">
            <input type="hidden" name="sales@greensynergytechnologies.com" />
            <input type="text" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Name" />
            <input type="text" name="phone" id="email" placeholder="Phone" />
            <input type="text" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Email" />
            <input type="text" name="website" id="website" placeholder="Website" />
            <textarea name="comments" id="comments" placeholder="Comments"></textarea>
            <input class="btn btn-outlined btn-primary" type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

### This is the PHP code that GoDaddy provides that I call webformmailer.php

```php
<?php

if ( !isset($_SERVER['SPI'])) {
        die();
}

if (!isset($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'])) {
    echo("CRITICAL: we seem to be running outside of the norm.\n");
    header("Location: http://".$_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"]."/");
    die("CRITICAL: Document root unavailable.\n");
}

$request_method = $_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"];
if($request_method == "GET") {
    $query_vars = $_GET;
}
elseif ($request_method == "POST") {
    $query_vars = $_POST;
}

reset($query_vars);
function customsort($a,$b) {
    // $a is array for form vars, $b is comma seperated case sensitive field order
    // this is case sensitive -- good idea to hrc that.
        $data = array();
        if ( strstr($b,',') == FALSE )  {
                $b = $b.",";
        }
        $ordering = split(',',$b);
        foreach ($ordering as $orderitem) {
                if ( ($orderitem != null) && ($orderitem != "") ) {
                        if (isset($a[$orderitem])) {
                                $data[$orderitem] = $a[$orderitem];
                        }
                }
        }
        foreach ($a as $key=>$val) {
                $data[$key] = $a[$key];
        }
        return $data;
}

function xmlentities($string) {
    return str_replace ( array('&', '"', "'", '<', '>'), array('&amp;', '&quot;', '&apos;', '&lt;', '&gt;'), $string);
}

$t = date("U");

$formhomedir = preg_replace('/.*\/home\/content/','',$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']);
$formhomedir = explode('/',$formhomedir);
if (count($formhomedir) <= 4) {
        $formhome="/home/content/".$formhomedir[1]."/".$formhomedir[2]."/data/";
}
else {
        $formhome="/home/content/".$formhomedir[1]."/".$formhomedir[2]."/".$formhomedir[3]."/".$formhomedir[4]."/data/";
}

$file_order = ".default";
$file_format = ".text";
$file_interval = ".15m";
$field_order = "";

if (isset($query_vars['form_order'])) {
    if ($query_vars['form_order'] != "alpha") {
        $field_order=$query_vars['form_order'];
        $file_order=".custom";
        $query_vars = customsort($query_vars,$field_order);
    }
    else {
        switch ($query_vars['form_order']) {
            case "alpha":
                uksort($query_vars,'strnatcasecmp');
                $file_order=".alpha";
            break;
            default:
                $file_order=".default";
            break;
        }
    }
}

if (isset($query_vars['form_format'])) {
    switch ($query_vars['form_format']) {
        case "csv":
            $file_format = ".csv";
        break;
        case "html":
            $file_format = ".html";
        break;
        case "xml":
            $file_format = ".xml";
        break;
        case "text":
        case "default":
        default:
            $file_format = ".text";
        break;
    }
}

if (isset($query_vars['form_delivery'])) {
    switch ($query_vars['form_delivery']) {
        case "hourly":
            $file_interval = ".60m";
        break;
        case "hourly_digest":
            $file_interval = ".60mc";
        break;
        case "daily":
            $file_interval = ".24h";
        break;
        case "daily_digest":
            $file_interval = ".24hc";
        break;
        case "digest":
            $file_interval = ".15mc";
        break;
        case "default":
        default:
            $file_interval = ".15m";
        break;
    }
}

$file = $formhome."form_".$t.$file_order.$file_format.$file_interval;
$fp = fopen($file,"w");

reset($query_vars);
switch ($file_format) {
    case ".csv":
        $csvkeys = "";
        $csvvals= "";
        $firsttime = "";
        while (list ($key, $val) = each ($query_vars)) {
            if ( ($key == "form_order") ||
                ($key == "form_format") ||
                ($key == "form_delivery") ||
                ($key == "redirect") ) {
            }
            else {
                if ($csvkeys != "") {
                    $firsttime=",";
                }
                $tmpkey=escapeshellcmd($key);
                $csvkeys = $csvkeys.$firsttime."'".$tmpkey."'";
                $tmpval=escapeshellcmd($val);
                $csvvals = $csvvals.$firsttime."'".$tmpval."'";
            }
        }
        fputs($fp,"$csvkeys\n");
        fputs($fp,"$csvvals\n");
    break;
    case ".html":
        fputs($fp,"<table border=\"1\" cellspacing=\"1\" cellpadding=\"2\">\n");
    break;
    case ".xml":
        fputs($fp,"<form>\n");
    break;
}

reset($query_vars);
while (list ($key, $val) = each ($query_vars)) {
    if ($key == "redirect") {
        $landing_page = $val;
    }
    if ( ($key == "form_order") ||
        ($key == "form_format") ||
        ($key == "form_delivery") ||
        ($key == "redirect") ) {

    }
    else {
        switch ($file_format) {
            case ".html":
                fputs($fp,"\t<tr>\n");
                fputs($fp,"\t\t<td><b>$key</b></td>\n");
                fputs($fp,"\t\t<td>$val</td>\n");
                fputs($fp,"\t</tr>\n");

            break;
            case ".csv":
                // content is already output
            break;
            case ".xml":
                fputs($fp,"\t<field>\n");
                fputs($fp,"\t\t<fieldname>".xmlentities($key)."</fieldname>\n");
                fputs($fp,"\t\t<fieldvalue>".xmlentities($val)."</fieldvalue>\n");
                fputs($fp,"\t</field>\n");
            break;
            case ".text":
            default:
                fputs($fp,$key.": ".$val."\n");
            break;
        }
    }
}

switch ($file_format) {
    case ".html":
        fputs($fp,"</table>\n");
    break;
    case ".xml":
        fputs($fp,"</form>\n");
    break;
}


fclose($fp);

if ($landing_page != "") {
    header("Location: http://".$_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"]."/$landing_page");
}
else {
    header("Location: http://".$_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"]."/");
}


?>
```

The after the form is submitted I get the mail just fine, but the area on the page that contained the form elements is blank. I inspected the page and saw and the blank area has a `<div id="preloader"></div>.`

Not sure where to go from here.

Comment: Is this code you wrote or is this part of a GoDaddy theme of some kind? If this is something that GoDaddy has provided you should be able to contact them about the issue and have them walk you through it. There should be another PHP file that gets the submitted data and builds the email with the collected data. You would need to debug that page.

Comment: The form code is my own, the form submit code is from godaddy. I have edited my post to include it.

Comment: I honestly would not use godaddy's php code. I would write your own, it is quite easy and will better if you ever decide to switch from godaddy in the future. http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php